# Monotone Convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Give an example of a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions $\{f_{n}\}$ converging everywhere to a Lebesgue integrable function $f$ such that

$$\ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{n} (x) dx <\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f (x) dx $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different counterexamples, two of which being:

- the mass goes to infinity:
  $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
  -1 &\text{if} & n<x<n+1\\
  0 &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$
- the mass concentrates around one point:
  $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
  -n &\text{if} & 0<x<\frac 1n\\
  0 &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$

Comment: It would also be a good exercise for the questioner to think about why this doesn't contradict any of the convergence theorems.

Comment: @danielson: I added another interesting counterexample.